# Unknown error? for XDocument.Descendants

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, linq-to-xml

I'm developing winrt app.
And it use the XML for Amazon Product Adversing API and something.
My XML is here:

```
<ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01">
<OperationRequest>...</OperationRequest>
<Items>
    <Request>...</Request>
    <Item>...</Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
    <Item>...</Item>
</Items>
```

and I used this for:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(res);
var itemsNode = doc.Descendants("Item");
foreach ( XElement node in itemsNode)
{
    //something
}
```

"res" is that string converted XML.
XDocument parsing correctly.
But, doc.Descendants("Item") returns Nothing.
Any suggest?

Comment: You are omitting the namespace (xmlns), looking for a good dupe.

Comment: o,hey.thanks for easy answers.

Comment: Just note that you need the strikken out part (`GetDefaultNamespace`) of my answer over there.